# How do you write "translation mine" in Japanese for academic writing?

Tags: translation, set-phrases, phrase-requests, jargon, academic-japanese

When you translate a quoted citation, how do you write "translation mine" in Japanese to let the reader know that it is your own translation rather than an official one (or, to contrast yours to the official one when you think the official one is inaccurate)? In Western academic writing, the customary marker is

> [translation mine]

directly following the quote (basically meaning "my translation" or "I translated the aforementioned myself").

I checked アルク and Weblio and did a Google search but didn't find a translation for this.

Comment: I would suggest that you write "translations are mine unless otherwise specified" (= 特に断りのない限り、訳は筆者による) at the beginning (or at the end) of your article. That will simplify the things (so I hope.)

Comment: そうですね、、「特に明記しない場合、邦訳は筆者による。」等と、末尾の「引用(参考)文献」(「註」のあと)の始めに書かれるとよいかと思います。

Answer (score 10, accepted):

引用文の終わりに、括弧に入れて

> (訳は筆者による) ←recommended
>   または、(筆者訳)  ← recommended
>   (拙訳)
>   (私訳)

のように書くとよいと思います。

Comment: Thank you! If the translation is already inside of parentheses, would it be:（「…」(拙訳)）

Comment: 拙訳 is OK in an essay by a novelist, but in an academic paper, I recommend "筆者訳" or "訳は筆者による" which looks more objective. ([Source](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=egm42bT4Hh0C&pg=PA240&lpg=PA240&dq=%22%E8%A8%B3%E3%81%AF%E7%AD%86%E8%80%85%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%82%8B%22&source=bl&ots=gXXcZNzJee&sig=OzSM7TfKr8GzokQzxs_qCAds9Bw&hl=ja&sa=X&ved=0CCkQ6AEwA2oVChMIl7bmwbDZxgIVwTKmCh1uoQBs#v=onepage&q=%22%E8%A8%B3%E3%81%AF%E7%AD%86%E8%80%85%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%82%8B%22&f=false))

Comment: @naruto そうですね、、、論集や雑誌に載せるんじゃなくて学位論文とかだとその方がいいのかも・・・？編集してみます